# RoR: Where is the "rails/info/properties" route defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running Rails 2.3.4. When I create a new rails project, the public/index.html file has a link named "About your application's environment" that points to "rails/info/properties". In dev mode, it gives a summary of the runtime environment. However, in production mode, it gives a 404 page cannot be found.

Could someone point me in the direction of how and where the "rails/info/properties" route is configured? I'd just like to understand how it's set up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The link fires off an AJAX request to `rails/info/properties`. The `properties` action is defined in the `Rails::InfoController` which lives in [**/rails/railties/builtin/rails_info/rails/info_controller.rb**](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v2.3.4/railties/builtin/rails_info/rails/info_controller.rb).

The route doesn't need to be explicitly defined because it conforms to the Rails default route of `:controller/:action/:id` (although there is no ID in this case and the controller lives within a *Rails* namespace.)

Answer (score 4):

It's configured within Rails itself (when in development mode). You can probably track it down if you look through the Rails initialization code.